# Is the period of a harmonic oscillator really independent of amplitude?

Tags: classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

Say we have a harmonic oscillator that obeys the force rule:
$$F=-kx$$
Hence, the equation of motion is:
$$\ddot{x}+\frac{k}{m}x=0$$
which may be solved analytically as:
$$x(t)=x(0)\cos\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}t\right)+\frac{\dot{x}(0)}{\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}}\sin\left(\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}t\right)$$
from which it is clear that the period of its oscillation in time is given by $T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}$. Now, as I understand the term "amplitude", it refers to the maximum displacement of the harmonic oscillator from its equilibrium position, which in this case is simply the origin of the $x$-axis. It follows that by setting $\dot{x}(t):=0$, finding the value of $t$ that satisfies this (there are infinitely many, but we just need one), and then plugging that value of $t$ into the function $x(t)$, I should get the amplitude of the oscillation. If we call that special $t$-value $t=t^*$, here is what I get:
$$x(t^*)=\frac{x(0)|x(0)|\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}+\dot{x}(0)|\dot{x}(0)|\sqrt\frac{m}{k}}{\sqrt{\dot{x}(0)^2+x(0)^2\frac{k}{m}}}=A$$
where $A$ stands for amplitude. But if you make the substitution $T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}$ everywhere you can in that expression, then you can check that $\frac{\partial{A}}{\partial{T}}\neq{0}$, and therefore it seems that the statement "period is independent of amplitude" (also known as the property of isochronism) is wrong? One way I found to make that statement correct is to assume that the harmonic oscillator starts at rest (i.e. $\dot{x}(0)=0$), but I'm not sure if people only meant for that phrase to apply to this starting-at-rest situation or if it was intended to have a more general applicability.

Comment: You must have a mistake somewhere. Consider that it's always at rest at some point on the path, and you could have started your stop-watch at that point. So you should absolutely not find that the answer depends on the value of $\dot{x}(0)$.

Comment: Your  are misreading the broad statement, which indicates you may vary period and amplitude independently in  a solution. It is *not* that amplitude and period are independent for the very *same solution*!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The period is independent of the amplitude keeping $k$ and $m$ fixed (and varying initial conditions). Your calculation tries to keep the initial conditions fixed and vary $k$ and $m.$

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer by showing where I might have been varying $k$ and $m$? I certainly don't have the impression that I was doing that, since when I differentiated $x(t)$ with respect to $t$, I treated $\sqrt{k/m}$ as a constant...(if that's what you meant).

Comment: @SurfaceIntegral You are trying to find $A$ as a function of $x(0)$ and $\dot{x}(0)$. To go from your initial position and velocity to the amplitude requires knowing the spring constant and the mass. So for fixed $x(0)$ and $\dot{x}(0)$, $A$ will depend on $k/m$ (equivalently, $A$ will depend on $T$).

Essentially, when you take $dA/dT$ while assuming $T$ is proportional to $\sqrt{m/k}$, you  are necessarily varying $k$ and $m$ while keeping $x(0)$ and $\dot{x}(0)$ fixed.

Comment: @surface Later on, you take a derivative with respect to $T,$ a function of $m$ and $k.$ This is not meaningful if $m$ and $k$ are constant.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you're making this so complicated.  Write
\begin{align}
x(t)=A\cos(\omega t)+B\sin(\omega t) \, ,\tag{1}
\end{align}
where $\omega^2=k/m$, $A=x(0)$ and $B= \dot{x}(0)/\omega$.  Since $x(0)$ and
$\dot{x}(0)$ are arbitrary, so are $A$ and $B$.

Now rewrite (1) as
\begin{align}
x(t)=C\cos(\omega t-\varphi)=C\cos(\varphi)\cos(\omega t)+C\sin(\varphi)\sin(\omega t) 
\end{align}
so clearly $A=C\cos(\varphi)$ and $B=C\sin(\varphi)$.

Obviously in this form the amplitude $C=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$ is arbitrary (since $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary) and does
not depend on $\omega$.  Now the amplitude $C$ depends on the initial conditions through
\begin{align}
C=\sqrt{x^2(0)+\dot{x}^2(0)/\omega^2} \tag{2}
\end{align}
but you still have the freedom to choose
$x(0)$ and $\dot{x}(0)$ to make $C$ whatever you want, irrespective of $\omega$.

Comment: Neat avatar. I added an obvious deconstructive comment to the OPs question, but I could move it here, if you wished; or, better, you could adopt it as your punchline.